# pgfplots: Change legend shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, charts

I have this code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{colour-list}{
red,style={fill=red}\\
orange,style={fill=orange}\\
yellow,style={fill=yellow}\\
green,style={fill=green}\\
blue,style={fill=blue}\\
}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,stage1,stage2,stage3,stage4,stage5
2017-11-20,1,2,3,4,5
2017-11-21,2,3,4,5,6
2017-11-22,3,4,5,6,7
2017-11-23,4,5,6,7,8
2017-11-24,5,6,7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\hspace{-5em}
\fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    table/col sep=comma,
    width=16.5cm,
    height=8cm,
    title=Chart Title,
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    date coordinates in=x,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel=\day/\month/\year,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    ytick distance=5,
    ymax= 40,
    tick align=outside,
    stack plots=y,
    legend columns = 5,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north, style={draw=none}},
    cycle list name=colour-list,
    ]
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage1]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage2]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage3]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage4]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage5]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\legend{Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I want only the entries in the legend, for their icon to be just a square. Currently, it's a line. If I add `legend image post style={mark=square*},`, it shows a square within a line. Any way to get just a square in the legend only (no line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
legend image post style={only marks, mark=square*},
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{colour-list}{
red,style={fill=red}\\
orange,style={fill=orange}\\
yellow,style={fill=yellow}\\
green,style={fill=green}\\
blue,style={fill=blue}\\
}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,stage1,stage2,stage3,stage4,stage5
2017-11-20,1,2,3,4,5
2017-11-21,2,3,4,5,6
2017-11-22,3,4,5,6,7
2017-11-23,4,5,6,7,8
2017-11-24,5,6,7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\hspace{-5em}
\fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
legend image post style={only marks, mark=square*},
    table/col sep=comma,
    width=16.5cm,
    height=8cm,
    title=Chart Title,
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    date coordinates in=x,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel=\day/\month/\year,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    ytick distance=5,
    ymax= 40,
    tick align=outside,
    stack plots=y,
    legend columns = 5,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north, style={draw=none}},
    cycle list name=colour-list,
    ]
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage1]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage2]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage3]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage4]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage5]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\legend{Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you want a square, I added

```
legend image code/.code={
        \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.2cm,0.1cm); },
```

to get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{colour-list}{
red,style={fill=red}\\
orange,style={fill=orange}\\
yellow,style={fill=yellow}\\
green,style={fill=green}\\
blue,style={fill=blue}\\
}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,stage1,stage2,stage3,stage4,stage5
2017-11-20,1,2,3,4,5
2017-11-21,2,3,4,5,6
2017-11-22,3,4,5,6,7
2017-11-23,4,5,6,7,8
2017-11-24,5,6,7,8,9
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\hspace{-5em}
\fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    table/col sep=comma,
    width=16.5cm,
    height=8cm,
    title=Chart Title,
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    date coordinates in=x,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel=\day/\month/\year,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    ytick distance=5,
    ymax= 40,
    tick align=outside,
    stack plots=y,
    legend columns = 5,
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.2cm,0.1cm); },
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
    anchor=north, style={draw=none}},
    cycle list name=colour-list,
    ]
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage1]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage2]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage3]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage4]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\addplot table[x=date,y=stage5]{data.csv}
\closedcycle;
\legend{Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
legend image code/.code={
    \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.15cm) rectangle (0.3cm,0.15cm); }
```

you get

[image]

Note that this also works if the draw and fill colors differ.